# Threads stop working C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing my online application in C++. Recently I needed to code a skill system for a game where one time executed skill puts 5 waves of same effects each wave delayed 0.5s after another. I came up with idea to use threads and sleep function, to prevent other players from freezing.

So my code looks like this:

```
struct monster_skill_info
{
    monster_skill_info(IMonster *_m, ICharacter *_o) : m(_m), o(_o) {}
    IMonster *m;
    ICharacter *o;
};

void FireStorm(PVOID v)
{
    INTERFACE(Monster)

    IMonster *m =   ((monster_skill_info*)v)->m;
    ICharacter *o = ((monster_skill_info*)v)->o;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       // magic happens here
       Sleep(500);
    }
}

void ISkill::FireStorm(IMonster* m, ICharacter* o)
{
    _beginthread(::FireStorm, 0, (void*)(new monster_skill_info(m, o)));
}
```

The problem is, after 24+- hours of uptime threads stop working. None of skill can be executed. I'm sure _beginthread stops doing its work. It's hard to debug because it happens after 24hours or even more. Is it possible that _beginthread stops working after some time? Can I do something with this?

Should I `delete v;` at the end of `FireStorm(PVOID v)` function? Might it be problem with memory leaks?

Comment: Your program probably has a bug. Make sure you do the usual daily yoga of fixing all warnings and running through Valgrind, ASAN and TSAN.

Comment: How many threads do you create like that? A bounded number? If you suspect a memory leak, what does profiling memory usage tell you?

Comment: @KerrekSB No it's not bounded number. It depends on how many players are online. In the worst scenario, the amount of threads is up to 500. No idea about memory usage since I've never used tools such as Valgrind or so. I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Well, if you have a `new` that's not matched by a `delete`, then you definitely have a leak, and if you do that an unbounded number of times then eventually you'll blow up...

Comment: What happens to the threads after they finish? Do you ever clean up the resources, using `_endthread`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that _beginthread stops working after some time?

By itself, not likely. But, it might fail because of some condition that the system has gotten into.

> Can I do something with this?

First line of defence would be to check the return of `_beginthread` and thus actually see if your idea that it doesn't work has merit. If it fails, check the reason for failure (`errno`) and you might have an idea what to do. If it doesn't fail, try another idea.

Of course, write this to some log, don't do this in the debugger.

> Should I delete v; at the end of FireStorm(PVOID v) function?  Might it be problem with memory leaks?

Yes, you should delete `v`, at end of `FireStorm` or at some other point after you're done using it. You are leaking memory, and that is certainly a problem after some time.

For example, your system may become very slow, because it does a lot of VM "trashing". So, say, `beginthread` might not actually fail, just take a *long* time to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak here

```
void ISkill::FireStorm(IMonster* m, ICharacter* o)
{
    _beginthread(::FireStorm, 0, (void*)(new monster_skill_info(m, o)));
}
```

Every time you uses new in C++ you have to delete it, you can use

```
monster_skill_info{m,o}; // vs (new monster_skill_info(m, o))
```

instead and the raii will delete it automatically when it goes out of scope

Remenber, if you allocate you have to deallocate always